# Is there a way that the file opens immediately in the program and not after?

Tags: python, file, authentication, tkinter

I am developing a notes app with a basic Tkinter login system that uses local files to store the data. However, when I register a user, the file isn't immediately created. Instead, the file is created after I terminate the program. This is a problem for me because I can't log in after registration, as the user file isn't created.

Here is the code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import glob

filelist = []

for file in glob.glob("*"):
    filelist.append(file)

def registration_duplicate_error():
    if username_content in filelist:
        messagebox.showerror("Error", "Username taken")
        screen1.deiconify()

def registration_success():
    messagebox.showinfo("Success", "Registration success")
    root.deiconify()
    screen1.withdraw()


def registration_username_error():
    messagebox.showerror("Username Error", "Please Fill in a Username")
    screen1.deiconify()


def registration_password_error():
    messagebox.showerror("Password Error", "Please Fill in a Password")
    screen1.deiconify()


def login_username_error():
    messagebox.showerror("Incorrect Username", "Incorrect Username")
    screen2.deiconify()


def login_password_error():
    messagebox.showerror("Incorrect Password", "Incorrect Password")
    screen2.deiconify()


def login_success():
    messagebox.showinfo("Login Success", "Login Success")
    root.deiconify()
    screen2.withdraw()

def home_screen():
    global screen3
    screen3 = Toplevel(root)
    screen3.geometry("240x240")
    screen3.title("Home")
#still in progress

def verify_login():
    global username1
    global password1
    global verify

    verify = []
    username1 = username_verify.get()
    password1 = password_verify.get()

    if username1 in filelist:
        with open(username1, "r") as userfile1:
            verify = userfile1.read().splitlines()
            if password1 in verify:
                login_success()
            else:
                login_password_error()
    else:
        login_username_error()


def login_screen():
    global screen2
    screen2 = Toplevel(root)
    screen2.geometry("240x240")
    screen2.title("Login Screen")

    global username_verify
    global password_verify

    global username_login_entry
    global password_login_entry

    username_verify = StringVar()
    password_verify = StringVar()

    Label(screen2, text="Login Screen", bg="blue", width=34, height=2).pack()
    Label(screen2, text="").pack()
    Label(screen2, text="Username").pack()
    username_login_entry = Entry(screen2, textvariable=username_verify).pack()
    Label(screen2, text="").pack()
    Label(screen2, text="Password").pack()
    password_login_entry = Entry(screen2, textvariable=password_verify).pack()
    Label(screen2, text="").pack()
    Button(screen2, text="Login", width=9, height=2, command=lambda: verify_login()).pack()


def register_user():
    global username_content
    global password_content

    username_content = username.get()
    password_content = password.get()

    if username_content in filelist:
        registration_duplicate_error()
    elif username_content == "":
        registration_username_error()
    elif password_content == "":
        registration_password_error()
    else:
        with open(username_content, "w") as userfile:
            userfile.write(username_content + "\n")
            userfile.write(password_content)
            username_entry.delete(0, END)
            password_entry.delete(0, END)
            registration_success()

def register_screen():
    global screen1
    screen1 = Toplevel(root)
    screen1.geometry("240x240")
    screen1.title("Register")

    global username_entry
    global password_entry

    global username
    global password

    username = StringVar()
    password = StringVar()

    Label(screen1, text="Register Screen", bg="blue", width=34, height=2).pack()
    Label(screen1, text="").pack()
    Label(screen1, text="Username").pack()
    username_entry = Entry(screen1, textvariable=username)
    username_entry.pack()
    Label(screen1, text="").pack()
    Label(screen1, text="Password").pack()
    password_entry = Entry(screen1, textvariable=password)
    password_entry.pack()
    Label(screen1, text="").pack()
    Button(screen1, text="Register", width=9, height=2, command=lambda: register_user()).pack()


def entry_screen():
    global root
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("240x190")
    root.title("Welcome")

    Label(root, text="Welcome", bg="blue", width=34, height=2).pack()
    Label(root, text="").pack()
    Button(root, text="Register", width=9, height=2, command=lambda: register_screen()).pack()
    Label(root, text="").pack()
    Button(root, text="Login", width=9, height=2, command=lambda: login_screen()).pack()
    Label(root, text="").pack()

    root.mainloop()

entry_screen()
```

I appreciate the help.

Comment: The file is created but `filelist` is not updated to include the new file created. So the newly registered username cannot be found when it is being verified in login screen.

Comment: `Button(root, text="Register", width=9, height=2, command=lambda: register_screen()).` you can remove the `lambda` and `()` if you are not passing any arguments

Comment: @Cool Cloud For some reason when I don't use lambda the thing automatically opens

Comment: @DanyalAsghar you should not use `()` that is the reason why the command is automatically executed without `lambda`

Comment: @acw1668 It worked thanks a lot.

Comment: @CoolCloud Got you thanks